# When creating a component in Azure ML studio, the component is not able to save files to output folder URI. The component transforms images and saves

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, azure-pipelines, uri, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML studio, we can build components to do different tasks in machine learning. I am creating a component that has one input: Input image folder (URI) and two output folders (URIs). The component takes images from input folder, transforms images using Pytorch and tries to save it to output folder.I am getting following error after executing command component from a yaml file.

Execution failed. User process 'python' exited with status code 1. Please check log file 'user_logs/std_log.txt' for error details.

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prep_1.py", line 177, in 
main(args)
File "prep_1.py", line 169, in main
prepare_data_component(args.input_data, args.training_data, args.val_data)
File "prep_1.py", line 114, in prepare_data_component
image.save(save_path)
File "/azureml-envs/azureml_7e9e1abac3aeb5e2560b92cd769d118a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2428, in save
fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/mnt/azureml/cr/j/50e4xxxxxxxx25a02xxxxxx/cap/data-capability/wd/INPUT_input_data/train/chickens/trial.jpg'

I want to know how to write/save images to an output URI from a .py file executed as a command from yaml file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: are you running a pipeline in azure devops to build the integration to ML? Has your script succeeded on your local machine? Could you share the demo of your yaml and script?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT, I can't share the code since it is company source code. But I was able to resolve the Issue. I was creating output URI folders of the component inside Input folder for better organization of data. But it seems using path= "./default" for output URI folders works best.

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT Just added the answer that worked for me. Thanks Ceeno for offering help. I am running these codes from azure workspace . In future we are planning to run it from azure devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating Azure ML components from a yaml file.
Here's how a simple yaml file to create a component will look like :

#### prep.yaml

```html
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandComponent.schema.json
type: command

name: prep_image_classification_pytorch
display_name: Data Preparation for Image Classification Pytorch
inputs:
  input_data: 
    type: uri_folder
outputs:
  training_data:
    type: uri_folder
  val_data:
    type: uri_folder 
code: ./
command: python prep.py --input_data ${{inputs.input_data}} --training_data ${{outputs.training_data}} --val_data ${{outputs.val_data}}
environment:
  conda_file: ./conda.yaml
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu18.04
```

## The command type will run the source python file which is prep.py

The prep.py file will take arguments from given yaml file (command line arguments) which we will parse through argparse library

#### prep.py

```html
ef parse_args():
    # setup argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # add arguments
    parser.add_argument("--input_data", type=str, help="path of input data")
    parser.add_argument("--training_data", type=str, default="./", help="output path of train data")
    parser.add_argument("--val_data", type=str, default="./", help="output path of validation data")

    # parse args
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # return args
    return args
    
def prepare_data_component(
    input_data: Input(type="uri_folder"),
    training_data: Output(type="uri_folder"),
    val_data: Output(type="uri_folder") ):
```

As shown in code above use "./default" for ouput URI folders. These folders will be created inside Azure MLs blob storage. Mentioning path of our choice inside azure blob storage did not work for me.